# Change text of a TextBox clicking a Button with Controls created at run-time

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to change the text of a TextBox when I click a Button: both Controls are dynamically created as run-time.

The Buttons and the TextBoxes are created every time I click on another Button.
The `Name` Property for each control is specified by the User, using a TextBox.

For example, the user inputs "Test1", then the Button is named `btn_Test1`, and the TextBox is named `txt_Test1`.

The Button should open a `FolderBrowserDialog` and after a selection has been made, the TextBox shows the path selected.

I'm using the following code:

```
protected void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button button = sender as Button;
    folderBrowserDialog.ShowDialog();
    string TextName = button.Name.Replace("btn_", "txt_");
    TextBox selectText = new TextBox();
    selectText = this.Controls[TextName] as TextBox;
    selectText.Text = folderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath;
}
```

however this part gives me null:

```
selectText = this.Controls[TextName] as TextBox;
```

I did check with the debugger when I create the controls, so `TextName` is setting the correct Name.

The Buttons and TextBoxes are inserted in a TabControls, the Tab Name is set to the value the user inputs, so the main TabControl gets 2 controls.

I'm using a hidden TabControl named "TabFolders" that will be the main reference for creating tab clones

I'm using this code:

```
private void CreateDynamicPathButtons(string TabName)
{
    TabPage MyNewTab = new TabPage(TabName);
    TabPage TabCopy1;
    tabControlEmpresas.TabPages.Add(MyNewTab);
    TabControl tc = new TabControl();

    tc.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(6, 6);
    tc.Size = TabFolders.Size;

    for (int i = 0; i < TabFolders.TabCount; i++) {
        TabFolders.SelectTab(i);
        TabCopy1 = new TabPage(TabFolders.SelectedTab.Text);
        foreach (Control c in TabFolders.SelectedTab.Controls) {
            Control cNew = (Control)Activator.CreateInstance(c.GetType());
            cNew.Text = c.Text;
            cNew.Size = c.Size;
            cNew.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(c.Location.X, c.Location.Y);
            cNew.Visible = true;
            if (cNew is TextBox) {
                cNew.Name = "txt_" + MyNewTab.Text + "_" + TabFolders.SelectedTab.Text;
            }
            if (cNew is Button) {
                cNew.Name = "btn_" + MyNewTab.Text + "_" + TabFolders.SelectedTab.Text;
                cNew.Click += new EventHandler(button_Click);
            }
            TabCopy1.Controls.Add(cNew);
        }
        tc.TabPages.Add(TabCopy1);
    }
    MyNewTab.Controls.Add(tc);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `button` is the Button control you're creating at run-time you mentioned, you're creating a TextBox control but you're not adding it to the `Form.Controls` collection (`this.Controls.Add([Control])`).

Also, you should assign a Location, using a logic that fits your current Layout, to position the newly created Controls. Otherwise, all new controls will be positioned one on top of the other. In the example, the new Control position is determined using a field (**`int ControlsAdded`**) that keeps track of the number of Controls created at run-time and add some basic layout logic.

But, if you want to keep a reference of these new Controls, you should add them to a `List<Control>` or some other collection that allows to select them if/when required.

```
int ControlsAdded = 0; 

protected void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox selectedText = new TextBox();
    selectedText.Size = new Size(300, this.Font.Height);
    selectedText.Location = new Point(100, ControlsAdded * selectedText.Height + 30);
    ControlsAdded += 1;
    this.Controls.Add(selectedText);
    selectedText.BringToFront();

    using (var fBD = new FolderBrowserDialog())  {
        if (fBD.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            selectedText.Text = fBD.SelectedPath;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After many attempts I did find a very simple solution.

```
TextBox selectText = new TextBox();
            selectText = button.Parent.Controls[TextName] as TextBox;
```

The button parent hast all the controls.

Answer (score 0):

with `selectText = this.Controls[TextName] as TextBox;`, you are trying to find button with replaced name which is not available in this case, and hence it returns null. This is logical mistake.

also  `string TextName = button.Name.Replace("btn_", "txt_");` does not replace button name, it just assigns replaced string to TextName.

The proper implementation would be

```
protected void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button button = sender as Button;
    folderBrowserDialog.ShowDialog();
    button.Name = button.Name.Replace("btn_", "txt_");
    TextBox selectText = new TextBox();
    selectText = this.Controls[button.Name] as TextBox;
    selectText.Text = folderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath;
}
```

Comment: string TextName = button.Name.Replace("btn_", "txt_"); here i'm trying to get the button's name and assign it to the string, then I look for that string in the selectText = this.Controls[TextName] as TextBox; I'm not trying to change the originals button's name, but since the names I assign are almost the same, if it's a button it starts with "btn_"  and "txt_" for text

Comment: did you debug and check whether what you are looking for is available inside this.Controls?

Comment: I did change the replace code string TextName = button.Name;
            TextName = TextName.Replace("btn_", "txt_"); the debugger shows only one control available, even though I dynamically added 4, so it's not there

Comment: If it is not there, it is not there. You couldn't add it.

Comment: but I can see them on screen, the 2 textboxes and the 2 buttons are there, so my code did add them

Comment: did you add them into your control? you may see them ok, but you need to add them inside this.Controls